# Prayaschittam citation

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras, smriti, prayaschitta

Does the Dharmic scriptures prohibhit Oral sex? For both sexes, man performing on woman and woman performing man, is oral sex prohibhited in Hinduism?

If so, what is the prayaschittam for oral sex? Please cite the sources.

I have read somewhere that Prayaschitta Sudhanidhi, has details about this, but neither the translation nor the text seems to not available online.

Comment: yes, non-yoni intercourse is prohibited. post-pubertal-woman-yoni is implied, so pedophilia, homosexuality and bestiality are included in the banned list as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Oral Sex is a sin (*paapam*) as per scriptures.**

> [ŚB 5.26.26](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/26/26/), Srimada Bhagvatam
>
> यस्त्विह वै सवर्णां भार्यां द्विजो रेत: पाययति काममोहितस्तं
> पापकृतममुत्र रेत:कुल्यायां पातयित्वा रेत: सम्पाययन्ति ॥ २६ ॥
>
> > If a foolish member of the twice-born classes [brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya and
> > vaiśya] forces his wife to drink his semen out of a lusty desire to
> > keep her under control, he is put after death into the hell known as
> > Lālābhakṣa. There he is thrown into a flowing river of semen, which he
> > is forced to drink.

> [Vasistha Dharma-Sutra 20.20](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vasistha-dharmasutra/d/doc116382.html)
>
> > 19. If (a Brāhmaṇa) intentionally (drinks) other spirituous liquor than that distilled from rice, or if he unintentionally (drinks)
> >     spirituous liquor extracted from rice (surā), he (must perform) a
> >     Kṛcchra and an Atikṛcchra, and, after eating clarified butter, be
> >     initiated again.
>
> > 20. **The same (expiation is prescribed) for swallowing ordure, urine, and semen.**

Comment: This only prohibits swallowing the semen. It doesn't say you can't just put the penis in the mouth and remove it right before ejaculation.

Comment: Yes but what about men performing oral sex on  women?? It's speaken in Prayaschitta Sudhanidhi

Comment: Isn't it clear @DanielChase? Putting any kind of liquids inside mouth is forbidden, performing it on women will clearly result in secretions of unwanted fluids and secretions from the privates (be it man or woman), and such fluids are forbidden to be partaken. Semen is not the only fluid secretions. There are several other secretions.  Hence performing oral sex on/by men or women, both ways, is a sin.

Comment: But it clearly says man should not drink, it doesn't mention any thing related to women. Als do you have any idea about Prayaschitta Sudhanidhi. It seems to have the specifics.